# Rails 3 - how with declarative_authorization test, if user is admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

In the documentation I found this part:

```
<% permitted_to? :create, :employees do %>
  <%= link_to 'New', new_employee_path %>
<% end %>
```

This is good, but I need to test, if the current user is admin, and if does, so then display some text... Something like

> if admin?

I can get this information from associations, like:

> if current_user.role == 0

but this is a bit dirty solution... support **Declarative Authorization** some cleaner and nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been looking for:

```
if has_role?(:admin)
  ...
end
```